# Proving Integer Modulo is Well-Defined

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have trouble figuring out this problem:

$h: Z_4 \rightarrow Z_6$ by $h([a])=[3a]$ for each $a\in Z$.
Prove that h is well-defined thus it is a function and that h is neither injective nor surjective.

Work: $[x]=[y]$ implies $[x]\equiv [y]$ (mod 4). Therefore, $x=y+4k$. Then $3x=3(y+4k)=3y+6(2k)$. Hence $3x\equiv 3y$ (mod 6) and $[3x]=[3y]$, which implies $f([3x])=f([3y])$.

I don't know if my work is right. I also cannot come up with any examples to prove that h is neither injective nor surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is fine, except that it should end "... which implies that $h$ is well-defined".

What is $h([0])$? What is $h([2])$?

Is there any $a$ with $h([a])=[1]$?